# Is the XTR-algorithm applicable over any finite field extension?

Tags: exponential-function, finite-fields, trace-map

For instance see [1,2], where the XTR is explained. Since they reduce $GF(p^6)$ to $GF(p^2)$ by considering their traces as representations of the equivalence class $Tr_{\mathbb F_{^{6/3}}}(a^{p^{m\cdot 6/3}})$ it is considerable to generalize this to consider for any $k$ with $3\mid k$ the trace $Tr_{\mathbb F_{a^{p^{k/3}}}}(a^{p^{m\cdot k/3}})$.

So my question occures: Is it possible to extend this method to any power of $p$, even if $3\not\mid k$? How about the field, where powers of $2$ devides $k$, that means $\exists m\in\mathbb N$ maximal, such that $2^m \mid k$. Let $n=2^m$, can't I reduce $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ to $\mathbb F_{p^{k/n}}=\mathbb F_{p^2}$?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTR

[2] https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164527/files/NPDF-23.pdf

Comment: It's been a bit more than 15 years since I worked out how XTR works. I share with you my impressions, but the details cannot be easily retrieved from my brain. 1) IIRC it may be possible to use the trace from $GF(q^6)$ to $GF(q^2)$ for any prime power $q$, but I'm not sure what the point would be, because we can equally well choose a prime $p\approx q$. 2) I'm fairly sure that the specific method requires $3\mid k$. Otherwise the description of the key subgroup fails. I recall trying relatively hard to improve the "compression rate" of XTR from $3$ to $30/8$, but I failed because of that.

Comment: (cont'd) 3) then I realized that the claimed extra security from this trick is vastly shadowed by the cryptoprimitives based on elliptic curves. I mean, in EC crypto they often tune it up so that Weil pairings take values in degree 30 extension field at least (IIRC that extension degree was called MOV, but I may be wrong). In terms of resilience againts such attacks to the DLP XTR can never (IMNSHO) be stronger than a MOV=3 EC. At that point I lost all interest in XTR. I was just the algebra guy in a crypto project, and I had fallen in love with EC.